# Find out file delimeter or regex

Tags: php, mysql, regex, csv, delimiter

I receive a file everyday with some data:

```
B024560HERR S, KARL-HEINZ          FAO031  D      F    18.07.17    01.08.17   14   LH 1162    18.07.17 10:30  12:35   FRA   FAO   FRA       1   LH 1163 01.08.17    FAO     03.01.17  1
    Frühbucher 10%
    inkl. Reiseleitung
    und Transfer ab/bis Flughafen
    *REPEATER, BITTE ZIMMERGEGENÜBER DER BAR 3ER
    UNVERBINDLICHER KUNDENWUNSCH
B024560HERR S, KARL-HEINZ          FAO031  D      F    18.07.17    01.08.17   14   LH 1162    18.07.17 10:30  12:35   FRA   FAO   FRA       1   LH 1163 01.08.17    FAO     03.01.17  1
B024560FRAU S, MARIA         FAO031  D      F    18.07.17    01.08.17   14   LH 1162    18.07.17 10:30  12:35   FRA   FAO   FRA       1   LH 1163 01.08.17    FAO     03.01.17  2
```

Link to this example file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c39km8htjqq9q4t/example.txt?dl=1

I need to import it to a mysql database.

So this should be divided like this (using | as a divider):

```
B024560 | HERR S, KARL-HEINZ    |       FAO031  | D    |   F    | 18.07.17    |  01.08.17   | 14   | LH 1162   |  18.07.17 | 10:30  | 12:35   | FRA   | FAO   | FRA      |  1    |LH 1163  | 01.08.17   |  FAO   |   03.01.17  | 1  |
    Frühbucher 10%
    inkl. Reiseleitung
    und Transfer ab/bis Flughafen
    *REPEATER, BITTE ZIMMERGEGENÜBER DER BAR 3ER
    UNVERBINDLICHER KUNDENWUNSCH  |

B024560  | HERR S, KARL-HEINZ       |    FAO031  | D     |  F    | 18.07.17  |   01.08.17  |  14   | LH 1162   |  18.07.17  | 10:30   |12:35  |  FRA  |  FAO  |  FRA    |    1  |  LH 1163 | 01.08.17  |   FAO  |    03.01.17  | 1  |

B024560  | FRAU S, MARIA  |        FAO031  |  D   |    F   |  18.07.17   |  01.08.17   | 14   |  LH 1162  |   18.07.17  | 10:30   | 12:35  |   FRA  |  FAO   | FRA   |     1  |  LH 1163  | 01.08.17   |  FAO    |  03.01.17  | 2
```

The best that I have done was with [this regex](http://[https://regex101.com/r/26qdlj/1][2]):

```
\s{2,}
```

So my problem is how can I find out the file delimeter ? Or is there another or better way to do this?
The idea is to read this file with php and import to mysql database.

Comment: Can you not read the file with `php` or `java` and fire `insert` queries to db?

Comment: Sorry I dont understand your suggestion. How will php "know" which is the file delimeter?

Comment: I would truncate multiple spaces into single space and then split each line by space. It would be much easier in php than in MySQL.

Comment: It might be that the example file was altered in some way in dropbox - can you examine your copy of the file in a hex editor and see if there is some character like 0x1D between elements?

Comment: You need to go back to whoever/whatever exported this mangled data and have it fixed there. Are you sure that there aren't any invisible characters (eg `\x1f`) being used as field separators?

Comment: @JackManey That is true! However, the company that sends this data are very complicated and inflexible to communicate and ask for changes...

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want:

```
(?<=\w)\h{2,}(?=\w)        # horizontal spaces with word character beneath
|
(?=HERR|FRAU)              # "HERR" or "FRAU" literally
|
\h+(?=\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}) # a date
|
\h+(?=\d{2}:\d{2})         # time of date in xx:xx format
```

See your [**modified demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/26qdlj/3) (and mind the modifiers!).

---

The whole snippet:

```
<?php

$text = <<<EOT
B024560HERR S, KARL-HEINZ          FAO031  D      F    18.07.17    01.08.17   14   LH 1162    18.07.17 10:30  12:35   FRA   FAO   FRA       1   LH 1163 01.08.17    FAO     03.01.17  1
    Frühbucher 10%
    inkl. Reiseleitung
    und Transfer ab/bis Flughafen
    *REPEATER, BITTE ZIMMERGEGENÜBER DER BAR 3ER
    UNVERBINDLICHER KUNDENWUNSCH
B024560HERR S, KARL-HEINZ          FAO031  D      F    18.07.17    01.08.17   14   LH 1162    18.07.17 10:30  12:35   FRA   FAO   FRA       1   LH 1163 01.08.17    FAO     03.01.17  1
B024560FRAU S, MARIA         FAO031  D      F    18.07.17    01.08.17   14   LH 1162    18.07.17 10:30  12:35   FRA   FAO   FRA       1   LH 1163 01.08.17    FAO     03.01.17  2
EOT;


$regex = '~
        (?<=\w)\h{2,}(?=\w)
        |
        (?=HERR|FRAU)
        |
        \h+(?=\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})
        |
        \h+(?=\d{2}:\d{2})
          ~x';

$lines = explode("\n", $text);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $fields = preg_split($regex, $line);
    if (count($fields) > 1) {
        print_r($fields);
    }
}

?>
```

See it [**working on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/9akXAq).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! I have put php language and corrected the output: |LH 1163 01.08.17|  -> |LH 1163 | 01.08.17|

Answer (score 0):

Kind of simple way.

Use `(?m)^(B\d+)((?:(?![ ]{9}).)+)[ ]+(.+)` and a callback function.

Pass $1, $2, $3 to callback.

Split $3 with \s+. $result = Join split array with |.
Return = Join $1 | $2 | + $result

```
 (?m)
 ^
 ( B \d+ )                     # (1)
 (                             # (2 start)
      (?:
           (?! [ ]{9} )
           .
      )+
 )                             # (2 end)
 [ ]+ 
 ( .+ )                        # (3)
```

Match example output

```
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 0 , len 7 ) 
B024560  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 7 , len 18 ) 
HERR S, KARL-HEINZ  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 35 , len 148 ) 
FAO031  D      F    18.07.17    01.08.17   14   LH 1162    18.07.17 10:30  12:35   FRA   FAO   FRA       1   LH 1163 01.08.17    FAO     03.01.17  1
```